# Why VS Code fails to debug sources with TS 3.7.1-rc syntax support?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have a code base and I am willing to use `typescript 3.7`, to be precise I use `3.7.1-rc`. I could build the source with the command line and even run tests in the command line, but when I want to debug the project using `F5`, it fails, vs code claims there are some errors, but it shows nothing in the `Problems` tab, but in the `Outputs` it says:

```
sample.ts(42,53): error TS1109: Expression expected.
sample.ts(42,68): error TS1005: ':' expected.
```

the source file is something like the following:

```
if (filterElements || configuration.classes?.filterElements) {
            const filter = filterElements || configuration.classes!.filterElements;
```

in which column 53 is where the question mark exists, and 68 is where the close parenthesis exists. I even tried the VS Code Insider, it behaves the same.

I have no idea what to do. I have the same error where ever I used `?` of `3.7`.

Comment: Did you set VS Code to use your TypeScript version too? [There's this version number](https://i.imgur.com/69OQ8vX.png) in the bottom right that you can click on to set it.

Comment: yes, and that's why it shows no error at `Problems` tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83628) to the discussion on GitHub to how to solve the problem.

Short Answer: Install `typescript@3.7.1-rc` globally, or configure the task.json file to reference the locally installed tsc( this is different than the selected version for [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling#_using-newer-typescript-versions).

Configure the `problemMatcher` of your  **task.json** to point to locally installed `tsc`

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "tsc",
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
            "problemMatcher": [
                {
                    "base": "$tsc",
                    "fileLocation": [
                        "relative",
                        "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/typescript/lib"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ],
}
```